# Why I can't debug Service Workers with chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, service-worker, fiddler, network-traffic

I almost got mad for a few weeks trying to check how a web page was updating itself. No network traffic, nothing found with Fiddler, service workers were not used, no background sync intercepted..

On the **left** you see the stock price **updating in real time**, on the **bottom** **no network traffic** was intercepted, and on the **right** neither any background service

[image]

Comment: In the first pic the filter in the Network tab is enabled, I forgot to disable before taking the screenshot, but anyway also fiddler wasn't see the traffic going out from chrome. And of course I wasn't going to check the web traffic from Kaspersky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the antivirus:

As soon as I disabled the antivirus (Kaspersky) the traffic from chrome's Service Workers became visible again both with **Fiddler**

[image]

And **Chrome**

[image]